# Highcharts reflow() after moving Y Axis to the opposite side

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart with two YAxes.
One of them is opposite.
At some point (after button click()) the opposite axis' side is changed to normal with this:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    chart_1.axes[2].opposite = false;
    chart_1.axes[2].isDirty  = true;
    chart_1.isDirtyBox = true;
    chart_1.reflow();
});
```

JSFiddle with full example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lvil/pomw0ruy/)
It doesn't work as expected though...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the edited code:

http://jsfiddle.net/pomw0ruy/4/

I am using `update`:

```
chart_1.yAxis[1].update({
     opposite: !opposite
});
```